# Clarification on Timer(s) that does not block or sleep the UI thread

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have a program that needs to periodically perform a quick operation. I would prefer it to run every 1 second. If a certain condition is met in the operation, it needs to then perform a specific action.

This periodic operation *must not* interfere with the UI in *any way* and must run for the life of the program. Not sure if I should use `System.Timers.Timer` or the `BackgroundWworker` in some fashion. If there is something better than those two, by all means tell me.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that under a certain condition, a Message Box needs to popup with an "exit" button that WILL block the UI and then shut down the entire program when the button is clicked.

Comment: Is the "certain condition" detected by the background thread or the UI thread?

Comment: @adv12 I guess I should explain a bit more about what I am doing. The timer (background thread) needs to monitor entries in a text file. It a certain entry crops up 4 times, then the UI needs to be interrupted and  a message needs to pop up on the UI letting the user know about this and then close the program.

Comment: I've updated my answer in response to your edit.

Answer (score 4):

`System.Timers.Timer` sounds like the ticket unless you need to update the UI with results from the background thread.  But you say it must not interfere with the UI in any way, so presumably you won't have this need.

To address your edit and comment on the question: you can still use `System.Timers.Timer`, but make sure you use `Control.Invoke` or `Control.BeginInvoke` to call the `AlertAndExit` (or whatever you call it) method.  (Instead of invoking something on the GUI thread, you could also just set a flag that's protected by a lock, but then you'd have to have a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` running just to check whether the flag had changed, which it sounds like you'd like to avoid.)

Comment: I added a quick edit, not sure if that changes your answer.

Comment: I assumed I would have to use an `Invoke` and glad you confirmed that. I am very comfortable with those as I have had lots of practice with those and `EnableRaisingEvents` stuff. Thanks! You have been a big help!

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you need done. If you don't need to marshal to the UI thread then a `System.Timers.Timer` will suffice. It runs on a separate thread from the UI thread so you could have it elapse/tick every second with no issues.